# Why does request.files not have the files that were sent?

Tags: reactjs, flask, post, fetch

I'm trying to upload a file to flask with fetch. What I do is onChange put the file in a useState hook and then onSubmit append it to FormData. After I send the file to my flask api with fetch. I put in a response to show me if the file is there or not and it keeps coming back as a blank dict.

Here is the react code.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

function App() {
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
  const fileInserted = (event) => setFile(event.target.value);
  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (file) {
      const data = new FormData();
      data.append("file", file);
      const resp = await fetch("/run", {
        method: "POST",
        body: data,
      }).then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data.file))
      .catch(error => console.error(error))
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="file"
          onChange={fileInserted}
        />
        <button type="submit" disabled={!file}>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the flask code.

```
    @app.route("/run", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def index():
        if request.method == "POST":
            if 'file' not in request.files:
                return {"file": request.files}
            file = request.files['file']
            return {"file": file}
        else:
            return {"file": "this a get"}
```

Comment: Because your FormData gets recreated on every render of the component.

Answer (score 0):

The FormData you're populating gets recreated as an empty object on every render.

You also don't need to use an effect hook to run the fetch...

```
function App() {
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
  const fileInserted = (event) => setFile(event.target.value);
  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    if (file) {
      const data = new FormData();
      data.append("file", file);
      const resp = await fetch("/run", {
        method: "POST",
        body: data,
      });
      // TODO: handle error/success
    }
    event.preventDefault();
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="file"
          value={file}
          onChange={fileInserted}
        />
        <button type="submit" disabled={!file}>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I have updated my code to match yours but the flask response is still telling me that there is no file found. I will update the question to show the new code.